# Libgdx apostrophe not rendering

Tags: java, text, fonts, render, libgdx

I'm trying to render out text in libgdx, however my apostrophes aren't getting rendered.

Things I've tried:

- Switching font (I've tried Arial, so it's not the font)
- Checking the bitmap graphic to ensure there's actually a graphic for it
- Imported the .ttf file and generated a bitmap font on the fly using FreeTypeFontGenerator
- Printed the string to the console to ensure that an apostrophe is even in the string

I'm stumped, I have no idea. Any ideas/solutions appreciated!

Many thanks.

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator fontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("mainFont.ttf"));
mainFontSmall = fontGenerator.generateFont(32);
```

Then later in the render update

```
System.out.println(level.introText);
mainFontSmall.setColor(0,0,0,introAlpha);
mainFontSmall.setScale(1f);
mainFontSmall.draw(sprites, level.introText, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Just did a quick test myself and I'm seeing apostrophes. Do you have some sample code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my original post with some code

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect in your code. Does this example (http://pastebin.com/84j1qr6N) work for you?

Comment: Turns out that my input was converting regular ' marks into ‘ and ’, characters which weren't included in my font generation. I just replaced all of these characters with regular marks at load for a quick and dirty solution. Thanks for your time and assistance though!